# Route all internet traffic through specific interface

Tags: networking

I have internet over wireless gateway 192.168.9.1.
As soon as I connect ethernet with manual ip and gateway of 192.168.1.1 the internet is a no go.

How do I force internet traffic over the wireless?

Thanks in advance.

Andy.

Comment: Don't set the default gateway of your ethernet connection?

Comment: Needs the gateway for 192.168.1.x traffic

Comment: Came to me ten seconds after posting - sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question - Netmask needs to be 255.255.0.0 on the ethernet.

Comment: What was it before that?

Comment: It's a while ago, but was likely 255.255.255.0 on at least one of the interfaces.